# Is there a read limit for Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I just ran a performance test (700 QPS read operation) on Firestore and it started to respond with timeouts after 5 or 6 minutes.

I thought Firestore scales automatically, but looks like there might be a limit for read operations...

Does anyone know if there is a read limit for Cloud Firestore?

Comment: If you are using the free plan, yes. Check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) out.

Comment: @AlexMamo Unfortunately not using the free plan.

Comment: It'll be hard to say why you're seeing a certain behavior without more details. Please share the code that others can run to reproduce the problem with, and the detailed logging output of what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Best Practices for Firestore in Datastore mode](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#ramping_up_traffic) it states:

> We recommend a maximum of **500 operations per second** to a new Cloud Datastore kind, **then increasing traffic by 50% every 5 minutes**. In theory, **you can grow to 740K operations per second after 90 minutes** using this ramp up schedule. Be sure that writes are distributed relatively evenly throughout the key range. Our SREs call this the "500/50/5" rule.

Comment: This applies to Cloud Datastore. I don't think it applies to Firestore.

Comment: Thanks, It seems that it works for Firestore (Native mode) too! Tried the "500/50/5" rule and it worked perfectly.