# in Firestore would it be more efficient to sort posts by unix time or by timestamp?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was originally going to sort out posts by unix time, but I read on documentation that monotonically increasing values slows down Firestore, increasing latency. would it be more efficient to have a timestamp field?

Comment: Please don't ask duplicate questions. Stick with one question as as new information becomes available, update the question to clarify it and generate more accurate answers. The topic is very subjective because it depends on the use case see [Hotspots e.g. a Narrow document range](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#high_read_write_and_delete_rates_to_a_narrow_document_range)

Comment: it's not subjective as these kinds of operations in high volume have degraded performance issues @jay - the question you linked to also does not answer sufficiently like the one provided below when quoting the actual firebase documentation. please reconsider the answer.

Comment: @DIGIByte The problem is the question is a duplicate; regardless of the answer. Please see [Duplicate Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) for reference. In regards to my comment, the OP states *that monotonically increasing values slows down Firestore* which is not accurate in *all* cases, so it's use case dependent (e.g. another app may not be affected because of a different use). There was no mention of 'High Volume' either.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says:

> "Creates new documents with a monotonically increasing field, like a
> timestamp, at a very high rate.".

"Very High Rate" being the key, I've collections over 50K documents but I the query rate is normal like only when users requests data or so. I am not exactly sure how much the "high rate" is but in general usage even will thousands of users there shouldn't be any issue.

The other causes that documentation explains:

> Creates new documents at a very high rate and allocates its own monotonically
> increasing IDs.
>
> Creates new documents at a high rate in a collection with few
> documents.
>
> Deletes documents in a collection at a high rate.
>
> Writes to the database at a very high rate without gradually
> increasing traffic.

*"We recommend starting with a maximum of 500 operations per second to a new collection and then increasing traffic by 50% every 5 minutes.*" You'll only run in issues if you are running those actions at too high rate and instantly.

Finally, don't forget to consider [Firestore Rate Limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55064038/13130697) answer says "In theory, you can grow to 740K operations per second after 90 minutes using this ramp up schedule." although I am not sure how reliable that stat is.